# How to work in TFS with one solution pointing different branches

Tags: tfs, branch

I am using TFS. I created a branch for one of folder/project in my solution. Now I have two branches (folders) with the same code. But my solution pointed only one (parent folder-branch. But from now I want to work with newly create son folder-branch.

I found two ways:

1. Redesign my solution to point newly created son folder-branch. My solution includes near 200 projects and this way will take a lot of job.
2. Don't change solution but change workspace by clocking parent folder-branch and mapping newly created to old place. This way also very complicated.

May be somebody will give me advise to another way. Easy way of using the same solution for several branches.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you will want to branch and merge at the solution level, not the project level.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need branching on project level and not to merge huge solution and reserve memory for all it.

Comment: Sorry to say but I can't think of a really great way to use TFS only branching projects.  Since it wasn't built to work that way, all the workarounds are going to be really kludgy.

Comment: i imagine Git is much flexible when it comes to branching?

Answer (score 2):

I have been following the ALM Rangers' guidance on branching, using their "basic" branching structure:

1. Created a "$/TP/Main" folder
2. Converted it to a branch
3. Created a "$/TP/Dev" folder
4. Branched from Main into "$/TP/Dev/Dev"
5. Created a "$/TP/Release" folder
6. Branched from Main into "$/TP/Release/Release"

My normal workspace maps from "$/TP/Dev/Dev" to my local "C:\TP" folder. That's where I do my day to day work, and the solution files are under there. When I merge forward to Main, and then to Release, the solution naturally comes with it.

The solution doesn't refer to any branch. It contains references relative to the disk location, so it all works in any branch or any machine.

Comment: No, this is not what I need. See answer # 1 of Ryan Rinaldi. He exactly defined my situation.

Comment: Actually, I'm talking about having the solutions under those branches, so, yes, the same thing.